# control that predictions are > 0 using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, gridsearchcv

I am using `GridSearchCV` in order to estimate the parameters of my regressor.
I use the scoring function [mean_squared_log_error](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_log_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_log_error) (and I would like to continue using it)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import xgboost as xgb

gs = GridSearchCV(xgb.XGBRegressor(),
                  param_grid={'max_depth': range(5, 10)},
                  scoring='neg_mean_squared_log_error', cv=5, return_train_score=True)

gs.fit(X, y)
```

y is always positive, but what happens is that some predictions within the 5 fold gridsearch happen to be negative (even if it shouldn't happen because my target variable is always positive) and therefore I get the error message

```
ValueError: Mean Squared Logarithmic Error cannot be used when targets contain negative values.
```

because the scorer is trying to calculate the log of a negative number (the unfortunate prediction).

Is there a way to control the predictions inside the GridSearchCV? How would you tackle this issue?

Comment: you could use the mean absolute error (MAE)

Comment: Or you could a use a custom wrapper which just wraps around the `neg_mean_squared_log_error` and clips the negative values to 0 before passing it to the scorer, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you have knowledge that your dependent (y value) is always positive you can use a loss function that constrains your predictions to be in the positive domain as well.

One example supported in XGBoost is [Gamma regression](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters) (see reg:gamma) or you can [design your own loss function](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/custom_objective.py) like the Mean Squared Log Error, you'd have to derive first and second order derivatives in that case.